# Why aren't all elements in the list deleted?

Tags: python, list

```
myList = ["Steven", "Jim", "John", "Eric", "Conor"]
print("My List: ", myList)
for elem in myList:
    myList.remove(elem)
print("My List: ", myList)
```

I want to delete each element of the list. I'm going through the each element of the list and remove it, but there's two left: Jim and Eric.
I've totally no clue why aren't they being deleted.
What's my problem? And how can I delete them?

Comment: Never change the list you are iterating over.

Comment: @KlausD. oh now I get it. Thank you